# How to fix "websocket is disconnected: Invalid HTTP upgrade" error using Starscream

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, websocket, starscream

I want to connect an iPhone to a web server running on my Macbook using MAMP and Starscream Library https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream
Installed using Cocoapods and set up the web server with this URL:localhost:8888
But I'm having a lot of headaches because the code doesn't work... I followed all the guides online, the official documentation and so on but none of them helped me...
Whenever I run the code, the console shows this message: websocket is disconnected: Invalid HTTP upgrade

So maybe it's my server that's broken? I tried using instead ws://echo.websocket.org/ and it worked!!! So I thought... Because it finally showed me: websocket is connected
But at the same time it wasn't!!! In fact the method socket.isConnected gave me false... After that if I called socket.disconnect() it doesn't
 work either, no messages show up.

```
import UIKit
import Starscream

class ViewController: UIViewController, WebSocketDelegate {

    let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string:"ws://echo.websocket.org/")!)//websocket is connected
    /*
    let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://localhost:8888/")!) //websocket is disconnected: Invalid HTTP upgrade
    */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()

        if socket.isConnected {
            print("hi1") //it doesn't get printed
        }
        if !socket.isConnected {
            print("hi2") //it gets printed
        }

    }

    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocketClient) {
        print("websocket is connected")
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocketClient, error: Error?) {
        if let e = error as? WSError {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.message)")
        } else if let e = error {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("websocket disconnected")
        }
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
        print("Received text: \(text)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {
        print("Received data: \(data.count)")
    }

}
```

Comment: socket.connect() is an async call. It means the socket does not connect right away. So when the control gets to socket.isConnected it returns false.

You need to call socket.connect() and then wait for the delegate methods to get called.

With regards to the "invalid HTTP Upgrade" you probably did not setup your server properly especially since you could connect to echo.websocket.org. It is hard to know for sure since you haven't included any information about the server setup.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

So I finally understood the problem: Apache doesn't support Web Sockets by default... that's why I got the error message. Then the code works with "ws://echo.websocket.org/". You just have to put all socket.x functions outside viewDidLoad() to make them work, for example socket.disconnect in a Disconnect Button, socket.write in a sendButton etc.

For example:

```
let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "ws://echo.websocket.org/")!) 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()

}

@IBAction func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    socket.write(string: textField.text!)
}
```

Comment: Hi i am not getting your answer , i am also facing same error, mu connect code not in viewDidLoad(). How you fix it ?

Comment: I am facing same issue here. I've tried your way but same error. Can you please provide a clear answer or code or link.

Comment: Also FYI, "ws://echo.websocket.org/" is working fine for me. With my url it is not working.